# How to access the programmatically generated elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access a dynamically created element using jQuery? Suppose I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "divHour" + i);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "btnHour" + i);

    div.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById("divHours").appendChild(div);
}
```

How can I access the buttons using jQuery?

Comment: bind them some data that you can use later. id, class, rel, anything should work. You can also use jquery's `data` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the button inside your original loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "divHour" + i);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "btnHour" + i);

    div.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById("divHours").appendChild(div);

    // moved after the button has been added to the DOM
    // do something with the button in jQuery
    $("#btnHour" + i).css({width:100})

}
```

Comment: $("#btnHour" + i).click( function () { alert('the button was clicked!'); } ); does not seem to be working...

Comment: It works now, first I had to append the buttons to the div, and the div to the document. Thanks again.

Comment: @burakk I put it last in your code block, which I think is how you got it working right?

Answer (score 1):

```
var $button0 = $('#btnHour0')
var $button1 = $('#btnHour1')
// ... etc ...
```

Once you have cached the jQuery object, use it as you wish...

```
$button0.css({width: 400}).animate({width: 200})
```

---

EDIT
To access all buttons in a loop...

```
// assuming `count` is the same as the code used to create the buttons
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var $button = $('#btnHour'+i)
    // do stuff with $button here
}
```

---

EDIT

Alternatively, to access all button elements that have an ID that starts with `btnHour`

```
var $buttons = $('button[id^="btnHour"]')
// do stuff to all buttons here
$buttons.css({width:300})
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how many buttons will be created, so I need a way like btnHour + i

Comment: the number of buttons will be the same as `count`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the HTML ID of the element. All you need to do is this:

`$("#html_id")`

jQuery uses CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons=$('button[id^="btnHour"]');
```

Will give you the whole collection of buttons

Your question is extremely vague, I suspect you want to access a specific button contained within a div that user interacts with. More details are required as to what you want.

EDIT: following is how you can access the index of a button within a click handler.

```
var buttons=$('button[id^="btnHour"]').click(function(){
   var buttonIndex= buttons.index(this);
    var div=$('#divHour'+ buttonIndex)
    /* can now interact with corresponding div*/
});
```

Another simpler way to find the parent div is :

```
$('button[id^="btnHour"]').click(function(){
   var $parentDiv=$(this).parent()
})
```

To target a specific button use `eq()` method

```
var thirdButton=$('button[id^="btnHour"]').eq(2);/* indexing is zero based*/
```

Comment: I'd like to access the buttons using jQuery just after they are created in the loop. For instance, $("#btnHour4"), how can I craft the jQuery selector using i, or is it not possible?

Comment: see update answer on how you can get the button index and matching div. You really don't need incremetal ID's if you use `index()` , can use common class and find matching div with jQuery `eq(index)` method also

Answer (score 1):

Give the buttons a class:

```
div.setAttribute("class", "myButton");
```

Then you can get all of the buttons with

```
$('.myButton') ...
```

For example, to loop over them:

```
$('.myButton').each(function(){

    console.log($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

If you want to identify each button, parse the number out of the class or give it a `data-mynumber` attribute and use `$(this).data('mynumber')`